# Rotation of 3 circles in square

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm doing a rotation animation of 3 overlapping circles and I have to find the number of pixels I need to move all 3 circles on the X-axis so that they are moving symmetrically. In the image below you can see the triangle with its altitudes (green lines). I want to shift all circles by the distance between the middle of the grid and the intersection of altitudes known as the orthocenter of this triangle.

Given a grid 8x8 of height and width equal to `a` pixels find the distance between the orthocenter of the triangle made by the intersections of the circle (as shown in the picture) and the centre of the grid. Each square edge in the grid is equal to `a/8` and the radius of every circle is equal to `a/4`. The distance that I'm looking for was marked as `x`

[image: Visualization]

P.S. This is my first post here. Please let me know if everything is clear

Comment: I am sorry oi say that your wording of the problem is not that clear. Do you want us to find the coordinates of $x$, the orthocenter of the triangle?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. There are two points the orthocenter of the triangle and the centre of the grid. I want the distance between them

Comment: @YNK I updated the description a bit. Can you check if now it is a bit clearer?

Comment: Why do you want to find the orthocenter of the triangle of intersection points ? Instead you should find the point that is the center of a big circle which is tangent to the three circles.  This point is located at $(-0.25, 0)$ and is different from the orthocenter.  But it is $(-0.25, 0)$ that you need to consider, and shift everything by $+0.25$ in the horizontal direction so that the rotation of the three circles is symmetrical with respect to the grid.

Comment: @GrabaCoffee Actually you are partially right. I asked this question on other math forums and they suggest marking the centre of the right circle `R = (1,0)` and doing the rotation so that the centre of the left circle will cross the `y=0`, which is `L = (sqrt(2), 0)`, then calculate the distance between those points and take the mean. So the actual answer should be `a(sqrt(2) - 1)/16 ` which is different by 3 pixels from the @Anatoly answer for `a = 200`

Comment: I am sorry, in my comment, I forget to mention that I am taking the edge length to be 1.  And taking the origin at the center of the grid, then the circles as they are given have centers at $ (-1,1),(-1,-1),(1,0) $ and radius is $2$.  The circle tangent to the three circles and containing them is centered at $(-0.25,0)$ with radius $3.75$, so shifting the centers of the three circles to the right by $0.25$ would center the big circle with respect to the grid.  Hence the center of the right circle should become $(1.25,0)$.

Comment: Correction.  The radius is $3.25$

Comment: @GrabaCoffee I'm afraid It's not that simple. The approach with drawing a big circle is correct but finding the value is not that easy. We need to solve a set of multivariant quadratic equations to find the `x_s` and `y_s` from `R^2 = (x - x_s)^2 + (y - y_s)^2` so that it has only 1 point of contact with another three circles. And since the triangle made from centres of circles is not equilateral we cannot easily find the `R` of the big circle. (Or maybe I'm missing some crucial knowledge :))

Comment: @GrabaCoffee Actually I was able to find it and you were right. The actual equation that fits all three circles is: `3.25^2=(x-0.25)^2 + y^2`. Nice. I would never come up with this idea though

Comment: Actually, it is very simple, assume the big circle is centered at $(x_s, y_s)$ and has a radius $R$, then for each of the three small circles, you can write $\\ (x_s - x_1)^2 + (y_s - y_1)^2 = (R - r_1)^2 \\ (x_s - x_2)^2 + (y_s - y_2)^2 = (R - r_2)^2 \\ (x_s - x_3)^2 + (y_s - y_3)^2 = (R - r_3)^2 \\$  Solving this quadratic system is done by finding the difference between equations 1, 2 and equations 1,3.  This would result in two linear equations in three variables, namely, $x_s, y_s, R$.   Solution is $\\(x_s, y_s, R) = v_0 + t v_1 $ for a certain $v_0, v_1$.  Substitute this into....

Comment: Substitute $(v_0 + tv_1)$ into one of the three equations gives you the two values of $t$.  Choose the value that gives the bigger positive radius.

Comment: @GrabaCoffee Drew a big circle and processed the animation. Looks OK to me :) If you want you can take a look as well: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F7kiha7lQypjnvqQCPX2sG_i7GGd0h00/view?usp=sharing
(You may have to wait for Google to process the video if you don't want to download it)

Comment: Nice.  Good work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The triangle $ABC$ is isosceles with base $AC$. By construction, the angles $\angle{KCH}$ and $\angle{CBH}$ are congruent, since they are complementary to the two base angles. Therefore, the triangles $\triangle{KCH}$ and $\triangle{CBH}$ are similar, and we have the proportion $KH:CH=CH=BH$.

Now, by simplicity, let us rename the base and the height of the initial triangle as $\overline{AC}=b$ and $\overline{BH}=h$. Also, let us set $\overline{OH}=k$ and $\overline{OK}=x$ (this last segment is what the OP is asking for). Using the proportion above, we get

$$\overline{KH}=\frac{b^2}{4h}$$

and then

$$x=k-\frac{b^2}{4h}$$

The coordinates of the vertices $A,B,C$ can be easily obtained by considering the equations of the three circles and have already been reported in another answer. From this, we have

$$k=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{11}{5}}$$
$$b=1-2\sqrt{\frac{11}{5}}$$
$$h=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{11}{5}}+\sqrt{3}-1$$

Substituting in the equation above (again by simplicity I omit the calculations and simplifications, but you can check the result [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B11%7D%7B5%7D%7D%20-%281-2%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B11%7D%7B5%7D%7D%29%5E2%2F%284%20%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B11%7D%7B5%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B3%7D-1%29%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)), we get a rather complicated fraction with various radicals that can be written in several ways.  Probably the most compact form is

$$x=\frac{\sqrt{55} + \sqrt{165}-19}{ \sqrt{55}+ 10 \sqrt{3} -10}\\ \approx 0.08559789...$$

or alternatively

$$x=\frac{\sqrt{11/5} + \sqrt{33/5}-19/5}{  \sqrt{11/5}+ 2 \sqrt{3} -2}$$

which gives the same numerical value. It is straightforward to express this result in terms of $a$, by taking into account that each square edge in the grid is equal to $a/8$.

---

Just for a rapid numerical check, approximated to 4 decimal digits, using a different method: the slope of the line $AK$ is given by $h/(b/2)$. Taking $$h= \left(\frac12 \, \sqrt{11/5}+\sqrt{3}−1\right)\approx 1.4737$$ and $$b/2=(1/2−\sqrt{11/5}\approx 0.9832$$ we have that the slope is $$1.4737/0.9832\approx 1.4988$$ The line passes through point $A$, whose $x$-coordinate is $-1/2\sqrt{11/5}\approx-0.7416$ and whose $y$-coordinate is $\approx -0.9832$. The intercept of the line $AK$ is then $$-0.9832+1.4988\cdot 0.7416\approx 0.1283$$

From this, setting $y=0$ in the equation $y=1.4988 x + 0.1283$, we get that the $x$-coordinate of $K$ is $$-0.1283/1.4988\approx -0.0856$$ in good agreement with the exact value calculated above.

Comment: Very nice explanation, Thank you :) And seems like a good answer. It's clean and verifiable and uses math that I forgot long time ago :D

Answer (score 1):

Let's work in units of $a/8$. Then the centers of the three circles are at $(1,0)$, $(-1,1)$, $(-1,-1)$. Let's call the vertices of the orange triangle $A, B, C$, with $BC$ the vertical line. Due to symmetry, the triangle is isosceles, $AB=AC$, but **not** equilateral, since the distance between the centers of the circles is not the same. The position of $A$ is at $y=0$, two units away from $(-1,1)$:
$$(x_A+1)^2+1^2=2^2\\x_A=\sqrt 3 -1$$
For points $B,C$ you need to use that the distance to both centers is the same:
$$(x_B-1)^2+y_B^2=2^2\\(x_B+1)^2+(y_B+1)^2=2^2$$
Subtracting the first of these equations from the second, you get $$4x_B+2y_B+1=0$$
Move $y_B$ term to one side, square everything, and get $y_B^2$ from the first equation:$$(4x_B+1)^2=4(3-x_B^2+2x_B)$$
This is a simple quadratic, and we want the negative $x_B$ solution. If I did not make any mistake, then $$x_B=x_C=-\sqrt{\frac{11}{20}}$$
After this, you calculate $y_B$ and $y_C$. The formula gets a little more complicated, but you can reduce it to $$y_B=-y_C=\sqrt{\frac{11}5}-\frac12$$
So now you have all the vertices of the orange triangle. Calculate the slope $m$ of $AC$. Then the slope of the perpendicular is $-\frac1m$. Now write te equation of the line with this slope, going through $B$, and find the intersection with $y=0$. That's the point you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @Andrei. If you look closely the points A, B, and C you mentioned are on the intersections of those circles not in the middle of them.

Comment: @Pawel I agree. But my point was that if the centers are not at the same distance from each other, then neither do the intersections. Or at least there is no obvious symmetry reason that $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral. And you can check from the coordinates that I've calculated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See post above how to get $x_B, x_C=-\sqrt{\frac{11}{20}}$ and the other coordinates of points of intersection.

[image]

$A = (\sqrt3-1, 0)$

$B =(-\sqrt{\frac{11}{20}}, -(\sqrt{\frac{11}{5}}-\frac{1}{2}))$

$C =(-\sqrt{\frac{11}{20}}, \sqrt{\frac{11}{5}}-\frac{1}{2})$

Since $CG$ is normal to $AB$, its slope $mx =\frac{x_A-x_B}{y_A-y_B}x$.
Equating this slope for $C =(-\sqrt{\frac{11}{20}}, \sqrt{\frac{11}{5}}-\frac{1}{2})$ gives you the shift constant $b$ in $DG = mx+b$ which then allows $mx+b$ to be solved for $y=0$. This yields

$G \approx (-0.0855978953, 0)$

So, with $1=\frac{a}{8}$, your shift of $\frac{-x_g}{8}$ in terms of $a$ is then

$x \approx$ $0,0107 \cdot a$.

```
The distance that I'm looking for was marked as x
```

Comment: `a` is spanning across 8 squares. The height of a triangle could not be more than the height of the grid. Perhaps you mean that the height is `sqrt(3)*a/4`? But then how did you calculate the edges/heights of the triangle. Can we assume it is an equilateral triangle?

Comment: It is not an equilateral triangle. The distance between the centers of the two vertically circles is $2$ units of $a/8$, while the distance from the center of one of these circles to the center of the circle on the right is $\sqrt{1^2+2^2}=\sqrt 5\ne 2$.

Comment: Butchered it. Am about to redo.

Comment: Sorry to say but I have no idea from where your numbers come from. It looks like you checked them in some online tool. I could also do this but there was a point for placing the `a` as a given param instead of a raw number. The animation will scale when someone resizes the screen

Comment: Yes, read last line of text.

Comment: Doesn't work well for me. And it's hard to determine who made the actual mistake. You in calculations or me in assumptions, because your solution is not based on mathematical reasoning therefore it is not verifiable (these are just numbers without any connection).

Comment: Check again! Fixed a criminal typo in the last line plus explained some bits.

Comment: Yup. The answer looks correct. I upvoted your solution but @Anatoly put some crazy good explanation on what he did to solve this so I deemed his solution as the answer. Nevertheless thank you very much for all the effort :)